# How to return meta properties of vertex property in Gremlin 3.4.0

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

One of my vertex property got his properties (meta properties). But when i return all vertex properties i only get value of that property but not his properties also. Is that possible to do?

This is what i've tried:

```
g.V(rootID).Out()
.Has("name", splitedPath[0]).Repeat(Out().SimplePath()).Until(Has("name", splitedPath[splitedPath.Length - 1])).Out()
                   .Repeat(Out().SimplePath()).Until(Label().Is("Recording")).Has("name", Between(partialPropertyName, partialPropertyName + "a"))
                   .Project<object>("id", "label", "properties")
                         .By(Id())
                         .By(Label())
                         .By(ValueMap<string, object>())
                   .Dedup().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to `Project()` again in they "properties" `By()` (in some way) because `ValueMap()` does not return metaproperties. Here's an example in Java which does that via `properties()`:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).project('id','label','properties').
......1>          by(id).
......2>          by(label).
......3>          by(properties().group().by(key).by(union(value(),valueMap()).fold()).fold())
==>[id:1,label:person,properties:[[name:[marko,[]],location:[san diego,[startTime:1997,endTime:2001],santa cruz,[startTime:2001,endTime:2004],brussels,[startTime:2004,endTime:2005],santa fe,[startTime:2005]]]]]
```

Comment: Yap this works. But do you know why result of query is different in C# and in JS? I know because of types but still in C# i get a lot of IDictionary as result.

Comment: i'm not sure i follow your question - perhaps you should ask a new question with some examples of the differences you're seeing.

Comment: I think it's not worth it to ask new question because I don't know how to ask :) But is there any difference between returning results in gremlin 2.6 and 3.4? Maybe that's what i don't understand.

Comment: 2.6? i'm not sure what version you're referring to. TinkerPop 2.x doesn't work with CosmosDB. there could be subtle differences between versions but again, without examples of what you're referring to, i'm not sure what you are seeing.